How to get the keys from org.apache.spark.sql.Column type in scala and put into a list variable?
I am trying to get the keys from org.apache.spark.sql.Column type variable and put it into a list so that i can do some schema comparison.
inputFieldMap: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = keys:[customerID,country],values[customerID,country]

expected output
newvariable: list[string]=[customerID,country];


Use map_keys function to get list keys from column of map datatype.
df.selectExpr("map_keys(inputFieldMap) as newvariable")

